# Panasonic MN39470PT CCD Sensor Timing

Tags: timing, ccd

The datasheet for the MN39470PT CCD sensor seems to be missing some details regarding the timing needed to drive the sensor. For this reason I'm very confused on how I'd drive the sensor particularly regarding why there seem to be six vertical clock inputs.

What kind of timing is needed to drive this sensor?

For reference the datasheet I'm reading is located here: https://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/distributors/Datasheets-24/DSA-474480.pdf

A backup copy is located here in case the above link does not work for you: https://web.archive.org/web/20210922020336/https://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/distributors/Datasheets-24/DSA-474480.pdf

Comment: You've probably seen it, but under optical characteristics (page 5) it mentions `1/7.5 seconds frame rate`. Apart from that, you are right - nothing is mentioned. Maybe there is an additional "Application datasheet" although I couldn't find anything on Google.

Comment: @Greenonline the frame rate would depend in part on exposure. For example if I was taking a one second exposure the max I could would be 1 FPS plus whatever time is needed to transfer the image. I'm not even sure why they put that there. Maybe it's a maximum meaning 7.5 FPS?